# How do I upload a hashed password to my database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a basic login page that uses this PHP code to upload directly to my database. When I use this code it works fine and it uploads everything to my table:

```
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = ($_POST['password']);
    $PhoneNumber = ($_POST['PhoneNumber']);
    $query = $con-> prepare("
    INSERT INTO Users (fName, lName,Email, username, pass_word,PhoneNumber)
    VALUES (:fname, :lname, :Email, :username,:password, :PhoneNumber)

    ");
    $success = $query-> execute ([
        'fname' => $fname,
        'lname' => $lname,
        'Email' => $Email,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password,
        'PhoneNumber' => $PhoneNumber
    ]);
```

But when i add the hash password function it just doesnt upload anything to the database at all.

```
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $Email = $_POST['Email'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];         
        $password = ($_POST['password']);
        $PhoneNumber = ($_POST['PhoneNumber']);
        $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $query = $con-> prepare("
        INSERT INTO Users (fName, lName,Email, username, pass_word,PhoneNumber)
        VALUES (:fname, :lname, :Email, :username,:password, :PhoneNumber)

        ");
    $success = $query-> execute ([
            'fname' => $fname,
            'lname' => $lname,
            'Email' => $Email,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $hashed_password,
            'PhoneNumber' => $PhoneNumber
        ]);
```

Update:
I made the changes that were suggested but I am still having the same issue. This is my updated code:

```
$password = $_POST['password'];


    $hashed_password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 15]);

    $query = $con-> prepare("
        INSERT INTO Users (fName, lName,Email, username, pass_word,PhoneNumber)
        VALUES (:fname, :lname, :Email, :username,:password, :PhoneNumber)

        ");
    $success = $query-> execute ([
            'fname' => $fname,
            'lname' => $lname,
            'Email' => $Email,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $hashed_password,
            'PhoneNumber' => $PhoneNumber
        ]);
```

Comment: You didn't parameterize it... compare `:username,$hashed_password, :PhoneNumber` with `:username,:password, :PhoneNumber`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1:

> ```
>  $hashed_password = password_hash($hashed_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
> ```

You are hashing an empty string.

You should be hashing the variable containing the password:

```
 $hashed_password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

## 2:

Your SQL query should **not** contain any variables, this is bad practise and potentially unsafe (for other non-hashed variables).

> ```
> VALUES (:fname, :lname, :Email, :username,$hashed_password, :PhoneNumber)
> ```

But you have `$hashed_password` as a hardcoded variable. This is incorrect on a syntax level and will cause SQL errors as it's [not encased in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60938399/how-do-i-upload-a-hashed-password-to-my-database/60938507#comment107812694_60938507).

You need to set this value in the `->execute` as you do with all the other variables:

```
    $query = $con-> prepare("
    INSERT INTO Users (fName, lName,Email, username, pass_word,PhoneNumber)
    VALUES (:fname, :lname, :Email, :username, :pwd, :PhoneNumber)

    ");
$success = $query-> execute ([
        'fname' => $fname,
        'lname' => $lname,
        'Email' => $Email,
        'username' => $username,
        'pwd' => $hashed_password,
        'PhoneNumber' => $PhoneNumber
    ]);
```

## SECURITY NOTES:

**A:**

You are not setting a `cost` value on your PASSWORD_DEFAULT (at time of writing this is BCRYPT) hashing mechanism. It is ***STRONGLY ENCOURAGED*** that you set this cost value to as high as possible, rather than the default of 10.

I would suggest setting the cost value to **at least** 15, and reading the [**PHP Manual Page**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which also sets out how to [find the ideal cost value of your server](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#example-1022).

```
 $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 15]);
```

**B:**

I would also highly recommend using one of the ARGON password hashing mechanisms. You will need to [recompile PHP with this enabled](https://framework.zend.com/blog/2017-08-17-php72-argon2-hash-password.html). I'm sure this will be made easier in coming PHP versions.

**C:**

I would also highly recommend ensuring your MySQL collations and character sets are `UTF8mb4_` prefixed unicode: `UTF8mb4_unicode_ci` with respect to your password storage column/table (Also ensure your column is long enough*).

* *that's what she said!*

Comment: Putting `$hashed_password` into the SQL string wouldn't work anyway, because it's not inside single-quotes as an SQL string literal. But no risk of SQL injection, since the hashing will not return a string with anything besides hex digits.

Comment: @BillKarwin I have updated point 3 and referenced your comment, thanks `:-)`

Comment: thank you this helps a lot, yes it was a typo where i have just password without the @. Thank you for the security suggestions, I will definitely be taking the advice to make my page more secure.

Comment: @Daniel.carv12 I have updated your question and my answer. Happy to help, cheers!

Comment: i made all the changes but i am still having the same issue where nothing is uploaded to the database. I updated the question  with my new code. Thank you.

Comment: @Daniel.carv12 what does your PHP error log tell you?

Comment: @Daniel.carv12  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel

Comment: it doesnt have any errors, only has warnings but none about the password

Comment: @Daniel.carv12 No MySQL errors at all? Are you sure the `$_POST` data is populated? (try `print_r($_POST)` at the top of the page. Does MySQL insert successfully but it is an empty row? Or does it not insert even an empty row? If there is a missing column (`pass_word` for example) can you tell me which columns are missing?

Comment: when i dont hash at all it populates all the fields but when i add the hash it doesnt populate any

Comment: @Daniel.carv12 But you have no errors? You need to turn on MySQL errors maybe; Please give details for the pass_word column, as in its length and collation/character set.

Comment: sorry for late response i sent you a photo of my pass_word column

Comment: I managed to get it to work, the problem was in my password field in the database. Thank you so much for your help !!!!!!

Comment: Yes, your field character length should be a minimum of 72 characters long for BCRYPT hashes, and longer for Argon2I ones  (This is stated on the manual page ). Glad you found it `:-)`